# Do I have a future with a torn acl?

Tags: injury

I am currently 19 years old. I tore my acl 4 times and have gotten 3 surgeries. I am not very eager to go through a 4 surgery. My last tear was about a year ago and ever since then I been gradually working my legs harder. I do a semi-intensive leg press and squat exercise about once a week, I cycle 5 miles everyday ( I try usually 5-6 times a week) and I work my calves everyday. I haven't seen a significant progress in the rehabilitation of my knee though. I have full range of motion but I have a constant soreness in my knee. And the other day the damn thing gave out on me out of nowhere (hasn't done that in months). I also have this very unatural snapping sound everytime i extend my leg . Fortunatley it's not followed by pain it just causes me discomfort to feel it everytime i walk. I keep wondering if it's because I been doing leg extensions not too long after my injury. I stopped doing them after 3 months after i found out their horrible for your knees. Could my 3 months of doing leg extensions cause any permanent damage to my knees? And what could i do to get my knee at least to not cause me any discomfort. I don't plan on doing sports every again I just wanna be able drive long distances or use the rudder pedals on a plane (i am a pilot) without it hurting.

Comment: These are questions you should be asking a qualified medical professional.

Answer (score 1):

I tore my ACL about half way, and was told at the time i would be on crutches for a minimum of six months, so that was over 30 years ago.  I was working on fire protection on the 8th tallest building in the world at the time, and taking 6 months off was not in the cards.  So i started working out like a fiend, and rehabbed my way out of the worst of it.
Fifteen years later, I finally dislocated my lower leg and took out what was left of the ACL and most of the cartilage.  So I had the graft done then.  I walked un-aided out of the hospital that day.
Such is the benefit of living a long time, medical technology got better faster than my ability to break things.  Dude, three knee injuries at 19 means you are headed down a dark road, wake up and fix yourself before the Docs can't fix YOU.  As of the first injury, i have suffered with knee issues for 40 years, and now, finally, I am getting my left knee replaced at age 62.  I keep thinking had I warmed up before sports, had I worn a brace when playing, had I thought things through I would not be in the position of having suffered with knee pain all that time.  Kid, this means at your age, you will have to suffer 43 years of crappy knees for what you did on 19 years just to get where I am!  Unless you think your jersey is going into the hall of fame someplace, best change course now!